# POST nested Json with Silex

Tags: php, json, post, silex

I'm new in Silex and I'm trying to retrieve nested Json Data with POST. Here is the Json part.

```
{
    "action": "opened",
    "number": 3,
    "pull_request": {
        "id": 35845110,
        "number": 3,
        "state": "open",
        "locked": false,
        "title": "Kie"
    }
}
```

My code works for action, number and pull_request but  I only want to use the data state in pull_request and I don't know how to collect it.

```
$app->before(function (Request $request) {
    if (0 === strpos($request->headers->get('Content-Type'), 'application/json')) {
        $data =json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
        $request->request->replace(is_array($data) ? $data : array());
    }
});

$app->post('/api', function(Request $request) use ($app) {

    $pullRequest = array(
        'action' => $request->request->get('action'),
        'number' => $request->request->get('number'),
        'pull_request' => $request->request->get('pull_request'),
        'state' => $request->request->get('state')
    );
    return $app->json($pullRequest,201);
});
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite simple actually. After you decode your json object, `pull_request` becomes an array, and therefore if you want to access `state` you need to refer to `pull_request` first. One way would be the so called `array dereferencing`, like this:

`'state' => $request->request->get('pull_request')['state']`

but in order to use that syntax, your version of PHP must be at least `5.4`.

You can also assign `pull_request` to a variable and use it like any other array up until now.

```
$pullRequest = $request->request->get('pull_request');

//....
'state' => $pullRequest['state']
```